# Creation of tradinview Alert does not function

Tags: conditional-statements, alert, tradingview-api

thanks for the great work.

This is a potential bug report:

I have configured an alert on tradingview using TMA overlay, see screenshot below.

However, i dont receive any alerts.

I have a doubt if the condition "is crossing" is correct. However there is no other way on tradingview to set up this alert.

I would be very thankful if you could have a look and help.

great thanks, best Alex
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBbiF.png)

see email above, i was trying to set up a trading alert

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshot is not the correct way to set the alert, because "3 Line Strike Up" is a boolean.
It doesn't cross.

The author did not include alerts for "3 Line Strike Up". You must add `alertcondition` to *bullSig*.
Something like that:

```
alertcondition(bullSig, title = "3 Line Strike Up"  , message = "3 Line Strike Up" )
alertcondition(bearSig, title = "3 Line Strike Down", message = "3 Line Strike Down")
```

Comment: Hello Gu5tavo71,

thanks a lot. this is great input.

Do you also know how to add the "new 'Any alert() function call'", which would allow to create 1 alert for if and only if any of the 4 events triggers?

I've tried replicating the code on this script: TMA Overlay_modified
But pine editor indicates: Error at 93:0 'input.bool' is not a function.

Best, great thanks, Alex

Comment: For a new question, you make a new post.